# How can I apply a Catmull Rom spline to a mesh object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to bend a mesh object using the Catmull-Rom algorithm, but I do not know where to start. I can obtain the positions of each triangle used to form the mesh object (thanks to Heisenbug).

I have begun to write some basic math to do the curving, but I'm not sure if its correct. Is there anyone who can point me into the right direction? I want to be able to do this in a C# script and so far I just have a mesh object.

```
public static Vector3 PointOnCurve(Vector3 p0, Vector3 p1, Vector3 p2, Vector3 p3, float t)
{
    Vector3 result = new Vector3();

    float t0 = ((-t + 2f) * t - 1f) * t * 0.5f;
    float t1 = (((3f * t - 5f) * t) * t + 2f) * 0.5f;
    float t2 = ((-3f * t + 4f) * t + 1f) * t * 0.5f;
    float t3 = ((t - 1f) * t * t) * 0.5f;

    result.x = p0.x * t0 + p1.x * t1 + p2.x * t2 + p3.x * t3;
    result.y = p0.y * t0 + p1.y * t1 + p2.y * t2 + p3.y * t3;
    result.z = p0.z * t0 + p1.z * t1 + p2.z * t2 + p3.z * t3;

    return result;
}

public Mesh CreateMesh(float width, float height)
{
    Mesh m = new Mesh();
    m.name = "ScriptedMesh";
    m.vertices = new Vector3[] {
        new Vector3(-width, -height, 0.01f),
        new Vector3(width, -height, 0.01f),
        new Vector3(width, height, 0.01f),
        new Vector3(-width, height, 0.01f)
    };
    m.uv = new Vector2[] {
        new Vector2 (0, 0),
        new Vector2 (0, 1),
        new Vector2(1, 1),
        new Vector2 (1, 0)
    };
    m.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
    m.RecalculateNormals();

    // -- retrieve mesh filter component that contains mesh data (points of each triangle)
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
    int[] triangles = mesh.triangles;
    //

    return m;
}
```

Comment: *"but I'm not sure if its correct."* Why not? What are the results you expect? What are the results you get? Are there specific problems? If so, what did you narrow that down to?

Comment: The result I'm expecting is a curved mesh object. So far, I haven't figured out how to apply the curving code to the mesh.

Comment: An arbitrary mesh? A plane? You're not giving us much to go on here. I fear it might be too broad a question.

Comment: An Arbitrary mesh would do as I want to know how the points within the triangles can be minipulated

Comment: Are you talking about subdivision surfaces? Unity is not strong in this, it is more a game engine than a modeling tool.

Comment: @David That would be Catmull-Clark. I'm assuming the OP is merely looking for a spline based deformer similar to a skinning operation.